# compile.bat and run.bat not work on OS system

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, terminal

I coded two batch file `"compile.bat"`and `"run.bat"` in windows in order to compile all the **java** file in `"src"` folder and run a specific file in `"classes"`, however when I try to run the batch files under MAC OS, the problems occurs.

1. When I double click "compile.bat" nothing happen
2. When I drag "compile.bat" to terminal to shows "permission denied"

Here is the codes:
**compile.bat**

```
 javac -d classes src/*.java 
 pause
```

**run.bat**

```
java -cp classes MyApplication
pause
```

Here is the Structure:

-compile.bat
-run.bat
|- src
|- classes
|- document
|- ref

[image]

Comment: What makes you think MacOS recognizes .bat files as executable?

Comment: I try to change the extension to "command", but it cannot work as well

Comment: Have you tried `*.sh`?  Have you set the executable attribute?

Comment: Oh, and have a look at Ant and Maven

Comment: you mean I change the code of "compile.bat" to *.sh but my files inside src folders are all java files. None of them are sh files

Comment: No change the `.bat` file to a `.sh` file

Answer (score 0):

Bat files are specific to windows in OSX you can use unix like shell scripts.

**compile.sh**

```
javac -d classes src/*.java
```

**run.sh**

```
java -cp classes MyApplication
```

should do the trick. You may want to read about shell scripts if you are going to run on Unix Like systems.

Comment: I try both change the extension to "command" and "sh", both double click and drag cannot work, when I double click nothing happen and when I drag to terminal, it shows "Permission Denied"

Comment: On terminal Run `chmod a+x compile.sh` and `chmod a+x run.sh` may be with `sudo` in front. Then from terminal run `sh compile.sh`

Answer (score 0):

**1,** Change file extension from `.bat` to `.command`

**2,** It is important to use `chmod u+x` to turn on **execute permission**  on terminal

- x is for execute permission.
- u is for user

**However**  Here is the error:

```
javac: file not found: src/*.java  
Usage: javac <options> <source files>  
use -help for a list of possible options
```

[image]